# Does memoryless property imply identical distribution of inter-arrival CDF's in a poisson process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, exponential-distribution, poisson-process

This is my result from finishing a problem in a stochastic process workbook:

"Since a Poisson process has the property of **stationary increments**, this implies that the inter-arrival times $Z_n=T_n-T_{n-1}$ are **identically distributed** without regard to the starting value of n.  That is:

$$\Pr(Z_{n-1} \le z) = \Pr(Z_n \le z)$$

$$F_{Z_{n-1}}(z) = F_{Z_{n}}(z)$$

For inter-arrival times of a Poisson Process, the CDF of step n-1 equals CDF for step n

---

How does this property relate to the **memoryless property** for **exponential** random variable, namely:

- A RV X is **memoryless** if X is positive, and for all real $t>0$ and $s >0$, then:

  $P[X > t +s] = P[X>t]~P[X>s]$
- A RV X is **memoryless** if for any s and t, we have:

  $P(X > t+s~|~X > t) = P(X>s)$

I was just curious... because CDF and memoryless properties seem similar to each other ... but the sign is backwards...